# How to get xml element values using XmlNodeList in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to store the element values which are inside the nodes "member" . I have tried the following code but I can't achieve it. How to get the values. Any help would be appreciated

**XML:**

```
 <ListInventorySupplyResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentInventory/2010-10-01/">
  <ListInventorySupplyResult>
    <InventorySupplyList>
      <member>
        <SellerSKU>043859634910</SellerSKU>
        <FNSKU>X000IA4045</FNSKU>
        <ASIN>B005YV4DJO</ASIN>
        <Condition>NewItem</Condition>
        <TotalSupplyQuantity>7</TotalSupplyQuantity>
        <InStockSupplyQuantity>7</InStockSupplyQuantity>
        <EarliestAvailability>
          <TimepointType>Immediately</TimepointType>
        </EarliestAvailability>
        <SupplyDetail>
        </SupplyDetail>
      </member>
    </InventorySupplyList>
  </ListInventorySupplyResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>58c9f4f4-6f60-496a-8d71-8fe99ce301c9</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</ListInventorySupplyResponse>
```

**C# Code:**

```
string a = Convert.ToString(oInventorySupplyRes.ToXML());
 XmlDocument oXdoc = new XmlDocument();
 oXdoc.LoadXml(a);
 XmlNodeList oInventorySupplyListxml = oXdoc.SelectNodes("//member");
 foreach (XmlNode itmXml in oInventorySupplyListxml)
 {
    // var cond = itmXml.InnerXml.ToString();
     var asinVal = itmXml.SelectSingleNode("ASIN").Value;
     var TotalSupplyQuantityVal = itmXml.SelectSingleNode("TotalSupplyQuantity").Value;
 }
```

**ResultView** `: "Enumeration yielded no results" and count = 0;`

**Edit 1:**

```
 string a = Convert.ToString(oInventorySupplyRes.ToXML());
                var status = oInventorySupplyResult.InventorySupplyList;
                XmlDocument oXdoc = new XmlDocument();
                var doc = XDocument.Parse(a);
                var r = doc.Descendants("member")
                           .Select(member => new
                           {
                               ASIN = member.Element("ASIN").Value,
                               TotalSupplyQuantity = member.Element("TotalSupplyQuantity").Value
                           });
```

Comment: @Gangadhar tagging done unforunately , now i just modified

Answer (score 1):

```
private string mStrXMLStk = Application.StartupPath + "\\Path.xml";
private System.Xml.XmlDocument mXDoc = new XmlDocument();
mXDoc.Load(mStrXMLStk);
XmlNode XNode = mXDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ListInventorySupplyResult/InventorySupplyList/member");
if (XNode != null)
{
   int IntChildCount = XNode.ChildNodes.Count;
   for (int IntI = 1; IntI <= IntChildCount ; IntI++)
   {
        string LocalName = XNode.ChildNodes[IntI].LocalName;
        XmlNode Node = mXDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Response/" + LocalName);
        // Store Value in Array assign value by "Node.InnerText"
   }
}
```

Try This `Code`. Its Worked

Answer (score 0):

try using this xpath

```
string xPath ="ListInventorySupplyResponse/ListInventorySupplyResult
           /InventorySupplyList/member"
XmlNodeList oInventorySupplyListxml = oXdoc.SelectNodes(xpath);
```

when you do `"//member"`, then, the code is trying to look for element named `member` from the root level, which is not present at the root level, rather it is nested beneath few layers.

Comment: oXdoc.SelectNodes("ListInventorySupplyResponse /ListInventorySupplyResult/InventorySupplyList/member")   I tried but iam getting nothing

Comment: string xPath = "ListInventorySupplyResponse/ListInventorySupplyResult/InventorySupplyList/member";
                 XmlNodeList oInventorySupplyListxml = oXdoc.SelectNodes(xPath);     Again getting nothing

Comment: hey try removing that  xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentInventory/2010-10-01/" from the root tag, everything works then

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you..

```
 string a = Convert.ToString(oInventorySupplyRes.ToXML());
 XmlDocument oXdoc = new XmlDocument();
 oXdoc.LoadXml(a);
 XmlNodeList fromselectors;
 XmlNodeList toselectors;
 XmlElement root = oXdoc.DocumentElement;
 fromselectors = root.SelectNodes("ListInventorySupplyResult/InventorySupplyList/member/ASIN");
 toselectors = root.SelectNodes("ListInventorySupplyResult/InventorySupplyList/member/TotalSupplyQuantity");

foreach (XmlNode m in fromselectors)
   {
      you will have value in `m.InnerXml` use it whereever you want..
   }
foreach (XmlNode n in toselectors)
   {
      you will have value in `n.InnerXml` use it whereever you want..
   }
```